# How to have multiple labels in a query formula?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-apps, google-sheets-api

Currently I have this formula :

```
   =QUERY(A:C,"select SUM(B), SUM(C) where A = date """&text("26/10/2017","yyyy-mm-dd")&""" label SUM(B) '', label SUM(C) '' ")
```

And this formula gives me an error if I put a second label. The formula works with just one selection and one label, but not with two.

I didn't find an alternative to this approach when searched?

I also tried to have just :

```
label sum SUM(B) '', SUM(C) ''
```

How can I have multiple labels, any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

`=QUERY(A:C,"select SUM(B), SUM(C) where A = date '"&text("26/10/2017","yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label SUM(B) '', SUM(C) ''")`

If you put `label` one time, it will work with next comma-separated list.